# Modify each row matching several criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm designing a staffing schedule for projects.

Staff members are assigned on day-to-day basis to different projects. For planning purposes, we want both a "staff per project"-view as well as a "project per staff"-view.

This led me to create a dataset consisting of one entry for each day/staffmember combination. With a dozen-or-so staff members and 365 days, this is a lengthy list to manually modify.

**Basically, this is the database:**
[image]

The real thing is some 5000 lines. Changing anything a big CTRL+F party.
Ergo; a macro to add staff planning.

On a different sheet, I built a simple form for data-entry.
People select a staff member, enter a project name, beginning date, and ending date. The macro is then supposed to find the row (s) matching the staff member and the selected date range, and change the project in the dataset to whatever is given as input.

I built the dataset, and begun working on code to locate the correct lines. I figured first making some code to set everybody's 24th of December to "Christmas" would be easiest.
To make things easier on myself, I figured coloring it red would be best.

```
Sub AddHoliday()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Sheets("2019-2020").Rows.Count

Next i

If Sheets("2019-2020").Cells(i, 1).Value = "24-12-2019" Then
    Sheets("2019-2020").Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
End If

End Sub
```

I expected to see every date equal to 24th of December to turn red, but I get the following error:

> ```
> error 1004: Object-defined error.
> ```

On the first line of the IF-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

- If should have been inside For Loop
- Date should be entered as Number, to be sure `24-12-2019` is recognized as `43823` by Excel
- Loop was being run on all the Rows, it should have been on Active Rows in the sheet

**Use:**

```
Sub AddHoliday()

Dim i As Long

With Sheets("2019-2020")

    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = 43823 Then ' 24-12-2019
           .Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm! This already helped me to change the entire thing to be able to change everybody's project planning for single days to a specific item; useful for giving people a Christmas break :)

Next job: Be able to input a range which will be changed for specific people, checking if they have planned things already. But let's hope I can do that myself. Again, many thanks!